# Fixed element inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, fixed

I probably asked this question before in a way =) But still, does anyone know if it's possible to have a fixed element inside an iFrame? I mean fixed i relation to the whole browser window?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - you cannot display items within an iframe outside of its boundaries.

Comment: I should also say ... you could set a fixed position on the iframe itself, then display the element, so that would be fixed within the browser window.

Comment: Yeah, so I don't want anything outside the actual iFrame, just fixed inside the iFrame, but in relation to the browser window. Think "Facebook app iframe", where you have your app in a an iFrame, when the user scrolls down, the whole page is scrolling right, both facebook and the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for "Facebook app iframe" - you have your app in a an iFrame, when the user scrolls down, the whole page is scrolling down, both facebook and the iframe:

Using JavaScript normally you would position your fixed element like so:

```
top = window.height() / 2 - $(id).height() / 2
left = window.width() / 2 - $(id).width() / 2
```

From within iFrame do this:

```
top = window.parent.pageYOffset + window.parent.height() / 2 - $(id).height() / 2
left = window.width() / 2 - $(id).width() / 2
```